# Determine whether the line formed between 2 points crosses the x or y axes

Tags: python, geometry

I'm trying to do this assignment:

> Write a Python function crosses(), to determine whether the line
>   formed between 2 points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) crosses the x- and/or
>   y-axis.
>
> The function prompts for the 4 values – x1, y1, x2 and y2. It outputs
>   one of the following messages:
>
> ```
> Line crosses both x and y axes
> Line crosses x axis only
> Line crosses y axis only
> Line does not cross both x and y axes
> ```

I read my lecture notes but it does not cover this topic. Is there any formula I can use to calculate?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you detect where two line segments intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect)

Comment: this question is one line segment?

Comment: One line segment... and a line (one of the axes) ... which is a very long line segment.

Comment: Get a piece of paper. Draw a coordinate system with x and y axis. Ponder what it means that a line crosses the x axis. Ponder what it means that a line crosses the y axis. All you need are a few boolean expressions, not a formula. There might be interesting special cases if a line is on an axis without crossing it.

Comment: Is no one going to mention that SO is not a homework site?

Comment: @Jarvis this is not a homework. is a revision question which i trying to understand

Comment: "*I'm trying to do this assignment:*" .. seems like homework to me. Quoting from Wikipedia, *Homework, or a homework assignment, is a set of tasks assigned to students by their teachers to be completed outside the class.*

Comment: even i don't write that you will still say its a homework to you. Ok u win :)

Comment: @KangChul why don't you try below answer instead of counting win and lose :D

Answer (score 1):

This should be fairly simple since you only need to check if it crosses the x-axis or the y-axis. You can just check if any one of your `x`s or `y`s shifts from positive to negative or negative to positive.

```
def intersects_axis(v1, v2):
  return (v1 <= 0 <= v2 or v2 <= 0 <= v1)


def determine_intersections(x1, y1, x2, y2):

  print("Checking if {}, {} and {}, {} any axes".format(x1, y1, x2, y2))

  intersects_y = intersects_axis(y1, y2)
  intersects_x = intersects_axis(x1, x2)

  if intersects_y and intersects_x:
    print("Line crosses both x and y axes")
  elif intersects_y:
    print("Line crosses y axis only")
  elif intersects_x:
    print("Line crosses x axis only")
  else:
    print("Line does not cross both x and y axes")


if __name__ == "__main__":

  x1, y1 = 1, 1

  x2, y2 = 2, 2

  determine_intersections(x1, y1, x2, y2)

  x2, y2 = 1, -1

  determine_intersections(x1, y1, x2, y2)

  x2, y2 = -1, -1

  determine_intersections(x1, y1, x2, y2)

  x2, y2 = -1, 1

  determine_intersections(x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

Which will give you:

```
Checking if 1, 1 and 2, 2 any axes
Line does not cross both x and y axes
Checking if 1, 1 and 1, -1 any axes
Line crosses y axis only
Checking if 1, 1 and -1, -1 any axes
Line crosses both x and y axes
Checking if 1, 1 and -1, 1 any axes
Line crosses x axis only
```

Answer (score 0):

Is problem is really about segments, not lines: some simple bit magic

```
def crossesaxes(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    q1 = (1 if x1 < 0 else 0) | (2 if y1 < 0 else 0)
    q2 = (1 if x2 < 0 else 0) | (2 if y2 < 0 else 0)
    q = q1 ^ q2
    answers = ['no crossing', 'x', 'y', 'crosses both']
    return answers[q]
```

(It is not specified whether segment with end point on axis `intersects` it)